# MvxBind: Failed to create target binding for binding?

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm showing `radio buttons` inside the `listview` and binded the `onClick` but I'm getting binding failed error.
Below is my ListView:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource QuestionList; ItemClick ChoiceCheckedClick"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_questions"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```

Item template:

```
 <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    local:MvxBind="Text OptionA; onClick choiceClicked" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    local:MvxBind="Text OptionB"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    local:MvxBind="Text OptionC"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    local:MvxBind="Text OptionD"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

My View Model:

```
  private IMvxCommand _choiceCheckedClick;
                public IMvxCommand ChoiceCheckedClick
                {
                    get
                    {
                        _choiceCheckedClick = _choiceCheckedClick ?? new MvxCommand<Question>(btnClick);
                        return _choiceCheckedClick;
                    }
                }

                public void btnClick(Question item)
                {
                    //Do something
                }
```

My Wrapper class:

```
 namespace EducationAppPCL.Utility
    {
       public  class QuestionWrapper
        {
           Question _questionItem;
           QuestionsViewModel _questionViewModel;

           public QuestionWrapper(Question questionItem, QuestionsViewModel questionViewModel)
           {
               _questionItem = questionItem;
               _questionViewModel = questionViewModel;
           }

           public IMvxCommand choiceClicked
           {
               get
               {
                   return new MvxCommand(() => _questionViewModel.btnClick(_questionItem));
               }
           }

           public Question QuestionItem
           {
               get
               {
                   return _questionItem;
               }
           }


       }
```

Below is my Model:

```
public class Question
{
    // [AutoIncrement,PrimaryKey]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> AssignmentId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Score { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string OptionA { get; set; }
    public string OptionB { get; set; }
    public string OptionC { get; set; }
    public string OptionD { get; set; }
    public bool RadioVisible { get; set; }
    public bool TexboxVisible { get; set; }
    public bool SubmitVisible { get; set; }
    public bool NextVisible { get; set; }

    public bool OptionASelected { get; set; }
    public bool OptionBSelected { get; set; }
    public bool OptionCSelected { get; set; }
    public bool OptionDSelected { get; set; }
    public string AnswerGiven { get; set; }

    public bool choiceClicked { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

I'm getting following error:

```
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 15.50 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 15.50 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
09-11 10:51:07.880 I/mono-stdout( 1929): MvxBind:Warning: 15.50 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
[0:] 
09-11 10:51:07.900 W/EGL_genymotion( 1929): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
MvxBind:Warning: 15.53 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 15.53 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
09-11 10:51:07.908 I/mono-stdout( 1929): MvxBind:Warning: 15.53 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
[0:] 
MvxBind:Warning: 15.54 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 15.54 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
09-11 10:51:07.920 I/mono-stdout( 1929): MvxBind:Warning: 15.54 Failed to create target binding for binding onClick for choiceClicked
```

Comment: Try using `Click` instead of `onClick`

Comment: When I'm using Click event it disables the radio button and yes it shows the binding failure too. Any thoughts ??